# Initializing dynamic default values for sub-elements on creation

Tags: polymer, polymer-1.0

I'm trying to work out how to make dynamic values available to sub-elements before the local DOM is initialised. I've created a custom element with a Google Map element embedded in it:

```
<dom-module id="place-picker">
  <template>
    <google-map api-key="..." />
  </template>
</dom-module>

Polymer({
  is: "place-picker",
  created: function() {
    this.apiKey = someFunctionToRetreiveApiKey()
  }
})
```

I want to provide the API key to the `google-map` element immediately. It needs to be before the DOM is initialised because the `google-map` element attempts to load immediately. But Polymer's `properties` are not evaluated . Using data binding `api-key="[[apiKey]]"` doesn't work because I haven't declared it as a `property`.

Comment: https://elements.polymer-project.org/elements/google-map seems to support "normal" binding to the `apiKey`. If you don't want to use this component you might be able to figure out how they do it from the source.

Comment: Good thinking... so I read the code for that element. It does use binding with a property but the problem is the property is optional and it continues to happily try to load the Google Maps API lib without an API key via the `google-maps-api` element. The library is only loaded on the `ready` event, which happens before the host element's `ready`.

Comment: Can't provide further assistance. I just remember seeing it. Maybe someone else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I prefer to use the "value" key of the properties object to set the value, but is should work similar to the created function mentioned above, you could also you the computed key.

```
   <dom-module id="place-picker">
     <template>
       <google-map api-key="[[apiKey]]" />
     </template>
   </dom-module>
   Polymer({
     is: "place-picker",
     properties : {
        apiKey : {
          type: String,
          value: functionToRetrieveApiKey()
        }
     }
   })
```

Comment: I tried this originally and couldn't get it to work as it seemed like the properties were being initialised too late. But it was actually an issue with the page loading. So this works fine, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I worked it out in a slightly hacky fashion. The context of the `created` callback is a raw HTML element, so you can simply set its attribute, which for some reason is evaluated as a property before local DOM creation. I ended up with:

```
# CoffeeScript
Polymer
  is: "place-picker"
  properties:
    googleWebApiKey:
      type: String

  created: ->
    @setAttribute("google-web-api-key", functionToRetrieveApiKey())

# Slim HTML
template
  google-map api-key="[[googleWebApiKey]]"
```